# C++/Flatbuffers - Verify table which is not root_type

Tags: c++, flatbuffers

Here is my fbs:

```
namespace Vibranium;

enum LOGIN_STATUS : int {
  INVALID_CREDENTIALS,
  LOGIN_SUCCESS,
  ACCOUNT_LOGGEDIN,
  ACCOUNT_INGAME,
  ACCOUNT_BANNED,
  ACCOUNT_LOCKED
}

table LoginRequest{
    email:string;
    password:string;
    client_hash:string;
    connection_id:uint32;
}

table LoginResponse{
    account_id:uint32;
    status:LOGIN_STATUS;
}

root_type LoginRequest;
```

This generates function called `VerifyLoginRequestBuffer` however there is no function called `VerifyLoginResponseBuffer` so I do not now how to verify `LoginResponse`.

My question is:

How in C++ I can verify table which is not marked as `root_type`?
Can anyone write an example as answer if it is even possible?

P.S.
I tried creating some unique function which can check all possible types like so:

```
template<typename T>
bool VerifyBuffer(flatbuffers::Verifier &verifier){
    verifier.VerifyBuffer<T>(nullptr);
}
```

So my plan was to provide `LoginResponse` like so:

```
bool check = VerifyBuffer<Vibranium::LoginResponse>(&verifier);
```

However `LoginResponse` inherits from `private flatbuffers::Table` which is a problem. So I am stuck inhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions like `VerifyLoginRequestBuffer` are "convenience" functions generated for the rout type. You can look at their (small) implementation, and call the exact same function for any other table type.

Comment: Can you please provide an small example? I tried what you suggested but it seems I can't make it work outside of the generated class/structs.

Comment: Here is what I tried `bool check =  verifier.VerifyBuffer<Vibranium::LoginResponse>(nullptr);` however this does not work. Any suggestion ?